# How the iOS built-in Calendar app sync with various calendar sources?

Tags: ios, calendar, google-calendar-api, caldav

I am trying to make a calendar app like sunrise and iOS Calendar app. How does iOS Calendar app syncing with various calendar sources like Google, Exchange and iCloud etc? What protocol does they use? Caldav? If I am going to make a app like that? How should I do so my app app's calendars' events are sync with these calendar sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS calendar uses CalDAV to sync with iCloud and Google Calendar, and AFAIK EWS to sync with Exchange. All the syncing is done by some EventKit daemon running in the background.

You can either just use EventKit to store your events and get all the syncing for free, or implement the protocols on your own. The current EventKit has some severe limitations, so it might not be the right approach to implement a fully functional calendar.

This is a nice intro on how to build a CalDAV client: http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/.

Comment: So I only need to make a CalDAV client if I only want to sync with Google Calendar?

Comment: If you only want to sync with GCal, you can build either a CalDAV client or a GData one. The former having the advantage that it works with plenty of other servers.